# Java Array Custom Function

Tags: java, arrays, performance

I want to convert a Vector3f array directly from array to another kind of data.
Here is an example:

```
Vector3f[] vecArray = new Vector3f[10];
float[] floatArray = vecArray.toFloats(); // <<
```

Is  that possible ?

Comment: Java provides `toArray()` but you usually have to use the wrapper `Float` (or `Double`, etc). You can write a method to do it but the syntax would look different from what you posted. Also an array of `Vector3f`(s)? Start with how you might represent one `Vector3f` as a single float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's nothing you can do to make that compile. (There's no equivalent of the extension methods in C# which would allow it, for example.)

The closest you'd be able to come would be to have a static method somewhere - whether within `Vector3f` or not - which you could invoke with a static import potentially:

```
import static ...Vector3f.toFloats;

Vector3f[] vecArray = new Vector3f[10];
float[] floatArray = toFloats(vecArray);
```

Comment: Yeah that should be ok. Thank you mate :)